# In Client, Unix stream socket is still in CONNECTED state even though server has closed the connection

Tags: sockets, unix, stream

We have an unix domain stream socket connection between client process -server process. When server is terminated, it is closing its connected sockets and its listening socket.

Sometimes, In client side, Socket is still in CONNECTED state (using netstat -anp | grep . Also, in client side, when recv() is called, it returns EAGAIN errno. This behavior is observed only SOMETIMES. But, not able to understand how this is possible.

If someone can explain how it is possible, then it would be really helpful.

Comment: Reduce the code to the minimal example and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly closing the connection?

If the server code is abruptly terminated without closing all connections, the operating system will still see this connection as active because the sever hasn't had time to clean up. The method to do this depends on the language used.